# eIMACS project 3 java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

This is the code I'm trying to use but whenever I run it I get an error that says java.lang.NullPointerException
null
and highlights the myContents.add(b);

```
import java.util.*;
public class Bin
{
    private String myName;
    private ArrayList<BinItem> myContents;
    public Bin( String name )
    {
        myName = name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return myName;
    }
    public ArrayList<BinItem> getContents()
    {
        return myContents;
    }
    public void add( BinItem b )
    {
        myContents.add(b);
    }   
    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "Bin " + myName + ":\n";
        for ( BinItem b : myContents )
            s += b + "\n";
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private ArrayList<BinItem> myContents;
```

You just declared `myContents` and never initialized it. Hence it is `null`.

Initialize it while declaring it.

```
private List<BinItem> myContents= new ArrayList<BinItem>();
```

Or you can do it just before using it.

Without initialization  your line

`myContents.add(b);`

at runtime looks like

```
   null.add(b);
```